# Getting different result with RegExp in TypeScript compared to the website regexr.com

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a very simple regexp to validate emails that looks like this:

```
^[\w.%+\-]+@[\w.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}$
```

When I enter this on the website as the regexp pattern, and "test@gmail.com" as the test string then it works as it should. If I try the string "test@gmail" it does not work because I don't want it to work with that.

But when I do this in TypeScript in validates even if the string is "test@gmail", not just "test@gmail.com", and I don't understand why.

Here is the relevant code snippet from TypeScript:

```
const regExp = new RegExp(`^[\\w.%+\-]+@[\\w.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}$`);
console.log(regExp.test(control.value));
```

control.value is the string "test@gmail".

It validates it, when it shouldn't.

Comment: `\`\.\`` is an unescaped dot that matches any character.

Comment: Should I escape the slash too? \\.?

Comment: Either double it or use a single one with a regex literal. `new RegExp("\\.")` = `/\./`

Comment: Thank you, but how would it look like with a regex literal?

Comment: [`var rx = /^[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/fH7j1f/1)

Comment: Thank you so much!